# Parsing custom BBCode with KefirBB

Tags: java, bbcode

I'm currently struggling on how to configure KefirBB to parse a custom BBCode. The custom code i'm trying to parse looks like this:

```
[quote=username] quoted text [/quote]
```

Is it even possible to configure Kefir to work with the username attribute? 
The result should be a simple HTML blockquote with the Username in the first line and the quoted text in the next line.
It would be great if someone could show me how to do this programatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <code name="quote1">
    <pattern ignoreCase="true">[quote=<var name="name" scope="escapeXml"/>]<var name="text" inherit="true"/>[/quote]</pattern>
    <template>&lt;blockquote class=&quot;uncited&quot; &gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;cite&gt;<var name="name"/> wrote:&lt;/cite&gt;<var name="text"/>&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;</template>
</code>
```